# How to hover over an area of a canvas element with Protractor

Tags: html5-canvas, protractor, end-to-end

I have a circle diagramme like this one:

[image: Circle diagramme]

And if you hover over the different colours, the color and text changes, like so:

[image: Yellow section][image: Grey section]

The diagramme is built with JavaScript. It consists of a `<canvas>` element that is being populated with data.

Now I want to write an end-to-end test for it using Protractor. Is there a way to do this?

This is the code of the `<canvas>` element, as is on page:

```
<canvas width="183" height="183" style="width: 183px; height: 183px;"></canvas>
```

And the code of the end-to-end test that I have right now:

```
it("should show a circle diagram with 33% activity", function() {
    expect(Backoffice.doughnutChart.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(Backoffice.doughnutChartText.getText()).toContain("33%");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hover the element with `mouseMove` [browser action](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions). It has an optional *offset* parameter that you can use to precisely control what area of the element to hover:

```
browser.actions()
    .mouseMove(Backoffice.doughnutChart, {x: 100, y: 100})
    .perform();
```